# Can't change volume in HTML5 Audio tag in FireFox

Tags: firefox, html, firefox3.6, html5-audio

On this page http://www.metrovancouver.org/services/solidwaste/Holiday/Pages/Song.aspx

I'm using a regular <audio> tag so users can listen to the song. I have a flash fallback on it too for users of IE.

In Chrome it works OK.

In FireFox 3.6.12, however, I cannot adjust the volume. If I put my mouse over the volume button, the volume slider appears, but as soon as I move my mouse to the slider to adjust, it disappears. I can mute the volume and unmute, but can't manually adjust the slider. Is anyone else having this problem?

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't look like you are the only one.  This bug has been reported in [bugzilla](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=533201) and is being looked into it seems.

Comment: <audio id=“myid” src=“mysrc”> ... </audio> followed by some JS that: myaudio = getElementByID(myid), then myaudio.volume = 0.3. That works for me